# Regular Expression For At Least One Number

Tags: javascript, regex

How would you create a regular expression for a value that should contain at least one number? The user can enter any special character, letter etc., but should contain at least one number.

I tried with `pattern="[\w+]{6,20}"` and

```
(?=.*\d)(*[a-z])(*[A-Z]).{6,20}
```

Neither are working.

Comment: Please, clarify:
Any number or one from a range?
The position of the number(s) inside the string.
Why you marked that answer as correct?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try using this pattern

```
.*[0-9].*
```

For 6 to 20 use this

```
^(?=.*\d).{6,20}$
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be like this? : .*[0-9]+.*
He writes "At Least One Number". Although the whole question is disappointing ( check comment ).

Comment: @Poniros the + is redundant. Any more digit can be matched with `.*` which is placed before and after the token [0-9].

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
/^(?=.{6,20}$)\D*\d/
```

Answer (score 0):

`/?=\D*\d/`

`/?`  is to check whether it has \D*

`\D*` means the following characters have no digits

`\d` refers to must have ending digit